# windows image viewer always shows first picture in folder

Tags: windows, windows-photo-viewer

I was used to viewing pictures in Windows viewer by using arrow buttons left and right (to open previous or next picture from the one currently showing).
From recently, it is not the case: no matte which picure I open from file explorer, when I press arrow right it does not go to the next picture but always to the first picture in the folder and than from than on...
Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: https://www.irfanview.com/ could be an improvement; it's highly customizable